# can we do URL-REWRITE for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, url-rewriting

We have built a WCF service for our customers and deployed the dlls. Everything works perfectly, but we have been told we have to change the URL of the WCF.

Lets say, our current WCF URL is like below

```
https://xxx.xxxxx.xxx/EGov/PostBox.svc
```

Now, they want us to change that URL to

```
https://xxx.xxxxx.xxx/EGov/TransferService.svc
```

It is easy to change the file name from PostBox.svc to TransferService.svc but we have do it for our 100 customers and that is impossible. So, we are wondering if we can do URL-REWRITE from CONFIG files.

If we can do the URL-REWRITE from config files, then we will email the config files to each customer to put it into the right folder.

I hope I made my question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure whether this will help you but i had some similar scenario where i have to rewrite the URL(for me i didn't have to show .svc file name to users.

```
    public class Route : IHttpModule
   {
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += delegate
        {
            //URL Rewriting 
            //---To remove the .svc extension service file name from URL----
             HttpContext cxt = HttpContext.Current;
            string path = cxt.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
            {
                cxt.RewritePath(path.Insert(1, "/ReportingService.svc"), false);
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help you at least in some way

Comment: thanks a lot. but this wont help me because we dont want to recompile the project. we just want to edit the config file if possible

Answer (score 3):

URL rewriting in WCF
[image]

Create a new WCF service application.

Add Global.asax file.

In Application_Start method add below lines:

```
 RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api/Service1", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
```

Add WebInvoke in Operation Contract of Service Contract (interface IService1).

```
[OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetData?value={value}")]
```

Build and browse Project.

Check this : http://gunaatita.com/Blog/URL-rewriting-in-WCF/1052